# How to initialize nil slices in a struct using reflect

Tags: go, struct, reflection, slice

For any given struct, I want to loop over its fields and set any nil slices to an empty slice. However, slices are unaddressable and hence not settable. How can I set the values of any nil slices?

Example:
https://goplay.space/#iV6OHkYVTru

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    IntSlice []int
    StrSlice []string
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{}
    fmt.Println(foo.IntSlice == nil)
    initNilSlices(foo)
    fmt.Println(foo.IntSlice == nil)
}

func initNilSlices(x interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        f := v.Field(i)
        if f.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
            t := f.Type()
            f.Set(reflect.MakeSlice(t, 0, 0))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're doing this - it's extremely rare that the difference between a `nil` slice and a 0-length slice is relevant.

Comment: I was trying to use a package that prints out empty configs. But it would not work with nil slices for some reason. Ended up using a different package...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update / modify `foo` in `initNilSlices()` if you pass `foo` because that will be a copy, and you could only modify the copy (and not the original value).

This is what the error message "hints":

```
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value
```

You obtained the [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) from a non-pointer value, and even what [`reflect.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) gets is a copy, so it doesn't allow you to modify it because it wouldn't be what you'd want.

You have to pass the address of `foo`:

```
initNilSlices(&foo)
```

And in `initNilSlices()` use [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem):

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(x).Elem()
```

With this it works and outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zm563E-zWuF)):

```
true
false
```